# How to use URL rewriting in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to use in-build URL rewriting provided by ASP.NET 4.0. I have tried the following code but i dont know why this is not working as i am totally new to this topic.

I have tried the code from the following link:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Easy-Steps-to-URL-2f792901/view/Discussions#content

But this code is working.
Please help me and it would be much better if any one can provide me code that is working..
**What i want to is:**
I am working on Some Social networking Site, client want when user tries to watch any other's profile then he will be visible the url like :**www.test.com/profile/UserName** This is my main goal. i didnt do URL rewriting so i have started from the beginning. But still i am not getting such type of example that meet my goal.Please if any one can, help me...

Comment: I believe you may have forgotten to add the code you were referring to: _"I have tried the following code"_

Comment: I think you haven't study my question carefully below that i have mentioned the link from where i got that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to write code to perform url rewrite. You may want to use IIS rewrite module extension, you can download it here http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
It is a Rules-based URL rewriting engine

for example you can rewrite testpage.aspx?name=testcase to /testpage/testcase via regular expressions

Comment: Please review my question again..